# Addhandler fcgid-script.php error

Tags: php, apache, cmd, addhandler, fcgid

Recently I started using Scriptcase and it requires me to first install PHP and apache.

During apache installation, I need to make some modification in httpd.conf, which is located in C:\apache24\conf

I added contents in the script as following:

[image: img1]

The installation was successful but leaving one error. I tried to restart but the error is still appears:

[image: img2]

I've Googled looking for solution but so far I found nothing.
Anyone maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a space after the handler `fcgid-script`.

It should be `AddHandler fcgid-script .php` not `AddHandler fcgid-script.php`

Similar issue on the following line with the `FcgidWrapper` directive.